# Earned calculus badge twice

Tags: support, badges

So, I didn't really but in the notifications area, it is listed twice.  That is, I got the calculus badge a few weeks ago with exactly 100 total score in calculus.  Then, a user was removed and I lost 10 reputation and my calculus score went to 99.  I still had the calculus badge, which is correct based on my understanding.  Then, yesterday, I answered another calculus question and got up to 101 and I was again notified that I earned the calculus badge.

Any way, this seems like a bug, though not exactly a big deal.  Just thought I'd bring it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You lost the tag badge when your score fell below 100. See [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

> My tag badge can't be revoked, like normal badges, right?
>
> Wrong. Tag badges, unlike normal badges, are automatically revoked upon a tag score recalculation if the tag is no longer eligible to have badges or you no longer have the tag score required for the badge.

So you did earn the calculus badge twice.

Comment: Very well, good point.

Comment: I wonder whether anyone has ever earned some tag badge three times?